# How to parameterize Bamboo builds?

Tags: rest, automation, continuous-integration, bamboo

**Please note**, although my specific example here involves Java/Grails, it really applies to any type of task available in Bamboo.

I have a task that is a part of a Bamboo build where I run a Java/Grails app like so:

```
grails run-app -Dgrails.env=<ENV>
```

Where "`<ENV>`" can be one of several values (`dev`, `prod`, `staging`, etc.). It would be nice to "parameterize" the plan so that, sometimes, it runs like so:

```
grails run-app -Dgrails.env=dev
```

And other times, it runs like so:

```
grails run-app -Dgrails.env=staging
```

etc. Is this possible, if so, how? And does the REST API allow me to specify parameter info so I can kick off different-parameterized builds using `cURL` or `wget`?

Comment: What and how will you change that variable?

Comment: Thanks @tmlai (+1) - the idea is that an automated process would kick off the build via Bamboo's [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/REST+APIs), passing in the value of the `<ENV>` param as a part of that RESTful call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a work around but I believe it can help resolve your issue. Atlassian has a free plugin call [Bamboo Inject Variables Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-variable-inject-plugin). Basically, with this plugin, you can create an "Inject Bamboo Variables from file" task to read a variable from a file.

So the idea here is to have your script set the variable to a specific file then kick off the build; the build itself will read that variable from the file and use it in the grails task.

**UPDATE**

After a search, I found that you can use REST API to change plan variables (NOT global). This would make your task simpler: just define a plan variable (in Plan Configuration -> tab Variables) then change it every time you need to. The information on how to change is available at [Bamboo Knowledge Base](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMKB/Resetting+Variables+via+a+REST+API+call+and+Dynamic+Release+versioning)