# Can the file specified for the Bamboo Inject Variables Plugin exist in the source repository?

Tags: continuous-integration, environment-variables, bamboo

I'm reading through the documentation about the [Bamboo Inject Variables Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-variable-inject-plugin/server/overview) and it is not obvious whether the file is supposed to be located at a URL, location on the build server, or collocated within the source repository.

In my case I would prefer the later option where it can be referenced within the source code repository itself I'm considering using this plugin if it supports this mode of usage. Unfortunately the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bamboo-variable-inject-task?_ga=2.6843186.1667633955.1494618399-1485389796.1494450585) and [community](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/tag/addon-com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-variable-inject-plugin/tg-p/category-id/atlassian-marketplace?_ga=2.6843186.1667633955.1494618399-1485389796.1494450585) links appear to be broken.

Related questions:

- [Bamboo Atlassian: How to share a variable between stages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628171/bamboo-atlassian-how-to-share-a-variable-between-stages/39714309?s=1|0.8024#39714309)
- [How to parameterize Bamboo builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507157/how-to-parameterize-bamboo-builds/23567850?s=2|0.6039#23567850)
- [Atlassian bamboo .Net plugins dependencies installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327618/atlassian-bamboo-net-plugins-dependencies-installation/38329061?s=3|0.1215#38329061)
- [Can Bamboo variables be overridden by a Script task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983084/can-bamboo-variables-be-overridden-by-a-task)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it appears that this is the default and perhaps the only place the Bamboo Inject Variables Plugin checks for the variable declaration file.

To test this I added a *Bamboo Inject Variables Plugin* task to look for a variable declaration file called `.build-vars`. When running the build I can see that the following error was generated which indicates that Bamboo was looking for the file under the staging directory where the source repositories code is cloned and built.

```
simple  15-May-2017 09:42:57    Starting task 'Inject Repo Variables' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-variable-inject-plugin:inject'
error   15-May-2017 09:42:57    Could not read variable file at 'E:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\KEY-KEY0-JOB1\.build-vars' as it does not exist.
simple  15-May-2017 09:42:57    Finished task 'Inject Repo Variables' with result: Error
```

I'm guessing that based on this it may be possible if one wanted to to set an absolute or relative path for the `Path to properties file` parameter but I haven't tried it myself as the result above is what I was looking for.