# Can Bamboo variables be overridden by a Script task?

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, environment-variables, bamboo

I'm interested in using a script task to override one of these Bamboo [plan variables](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/defining-plan-variables-289276859.html) for subsequent tasks but I'm not sure if it's possible or how to go about doing so. It appears that Bamboo allows for various levels of variable overrides for Build Plans all the way down to particular branches however they all seem to require defining the values within the Bamboo UI. The problem with this is that it requires admin privileges to modify these variables whereas some of them need to be modified by developers that do not have this level of access. As a solution I want to be able to specify some variable overrides in files that exist in the source repository itself.

### Attempt 1: Overriding environment variables

I've attempted to set the environment variables exposed by Bamboo using a Powershell script and specifying something like `$env:bamboo_xyz = 'ABC'` but it doesn't seem to have an effect past the task context in which it was specified in. Presumably Bamboo must be re-setting the environment variables individually for each task or executing them within their own contexts but it's not clear to me exactly from the documentation.

UPDATE: It appears from some testing that environment variables set in one Script task are not available in subsequent Script tasks in the same Job. This leaves me with no apparent way to override variables based on anything other than hard coded values in Bamboo.

### Attempt 2: Using the **Bamboo Inject Variables Plugin** task

I've tried using the [Bamboo Inject Variables Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-variable-inject-plugin/server/overview) task to override variables but because what appears to be a required namespace parameter it only seems to be able to define new variables and not override existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

Enviroment variables are only valid in the current session. So if bamboo starts one script ( one powershell session ) completes that and then start a new powershell script ( New Session ) the enviroment variable will not be kept.

So then there are a few options, set the variable in each script. 
Or set it using registry at the start of the process. And if ncessary set it back to default value in the last step/script.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying about environment variables and sessions. With regard to your comment on `using registry` do you mean the Windows registry or is there are different way to register values for bamboo variables I'm overlooking?

Comment: I think this would help you along. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx

It shows how to use .Net methods from powershell to set permanent environment variables.

Comment: Thanks Kjetil, now it makes sense why you suggest setting the variable back afterwords as well seeing that they would be either user or system level. I was aware of this ability using the `setx` command as well I'm not as familiar with this overload of the `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` although it looks like it's been around since .NET 2.0.